# Testing a class method for a model using Rspec and FactoryGirl in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, shopping-cart, rspec-rails

I am new to Rspec and FactoryGirl for testing ROR applications. I am trying to test a model class method `add_product(product_id)` and it keeps failing though it works when i try the same on the browser. here is the code for the model:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, inverse_of: :cart

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end
end
```

Here is the failing spec for the cart model:

```
describe Cart do
  before(:each) do
    @cart = FactoryGirl.create(:cart)
    @product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
    @line_item = FactoryGirl.create(:line_item, product_id: @product.id, cart_id: @cart.id)
  end
  it 'increases the quantity of line_item when a similar product is added' do
    lambda {@cart.add_product(@product.id)}.should change {@line_item.quantity}.by(1)
  end
end
```

This fails and i get this message from Rspec `Failure/Error: lambda {@cart.add_product(@product.id)}.should change {@line_item.quantity}.by(1)
       result should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantity is being updated, but you're never persisting the data. So the data is never hitting the database and the test is never going to see a change. You'll run into the same problem with .build where it is not persisted until you explicitly say so.  You can change this by doing.

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, inverse_of: :cart

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
      current_item.save
    else
      current_item = line_items.create(:product_id => product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric for the quick response, but the test still fails after persisting `current_item` is there another way i can re-write the spec to perform the same test?

Comment: Sure you can do `@cart.add_product(@product.id).quantity.should eq 2`

The issue with this approach is that it doesn't test whether or not your item persisted that way. It just tests that your logic works.

Comment: I just wanted to test the logic, i have the item persisted on different part of my code i'll test how it is persisted on that part. your answer is what i was looking for.